# Помогите ошибку расшифровать

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-gradle

Я попросту добавил поддержку com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0 в зависимости, я попытался сделать replace но выпала ошибка, мол аргумент для замены не указан.. Крч, я думаю реплэйс лишний и нужно понять почему у коллеге это не возникает, а у меня возникает:

Зависимости в build.gradle:

```
dependencies {

    // implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    // Internet
    def retrofit_version = '2.9.0'
    def okhttp_version = '5.0.0-alpha.11'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp_version"

    // Jsoup для получения содержимого html страницы pastbin
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.16.1'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    // implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
   

}
```

Ошибка при сборке:

```
Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.8.0] AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:49:5-100:19 to override.
```

Answer (score 1):

Я кажется понял суть ошибки, поддержка уже включена другим импортом, дополнительно указывать import android.support.v4.app.*; не требуется. По крайней мере NotificationCompact и без import android.support.v4.app.*; есть в import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

P.s ночью нужно спать, а не код писать, ну если только чуть-чуть - внимательность ни к черту